# If a question was migrated, what happened to the bounty?

Tags: support, migration, bounty, specific-question

I asked moderator to migrate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018081/make-virtualbox-kernel-modules-builtin-rather-than-modules-half-done), before that I started a bounty with 50 reputation, and now it seems gone ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/44636/revisions), you started the bounty on August 5th, and it expired on August 13th with no winning answer chosen. It didn't get migrated until August 18th

Questions with bounties can't be migrated anyway, so if you put a bounty on a question it's usually stuck on the site it's on for a while